# Seeking the book of Rav Moshe Taku

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rishonim, anthropomorphism

I read in a post on mi yodeya [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/do-the-rishonim-that-hold-g-d-can-have-physical-form-e-g-rav-moshe-taku-etc) that this Chacham, [Rav Moshe Ben Chasday Mitaku](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%95) wrote that G-d has a body. I am sure that the text is very interesting and I am curious to understand what he means. Is it possible to read the original text online?
If someone can help me I will be very grateful.

 [This](http://www.teachittome.com/seforim2/seforim/kesav_tamim.pdf) is very hard to read.

Comment: The only current extant is the version from the link that you have, although some of it is typed up [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/chazal/maamar.asp?id=273). However, several rabbis have dealt with his views, such as Rav Menachem Mendel Kasher in [Torah Sheleimah vol. 16 pp. 308-322](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51462&st=&pgnum=314), [Rabbi David Sedley](http://www.hashkafacircle.com/journal/R3_DS_Taku.pdf) (whose views are somewhat unusual) and Rabbi Ahron Lopiansky, "The Corporeality Which Never Was," *Dialogue* 5 (Fall 2014)

Comment: It should be noted that his view is really only significant to the historian. His views do not reflect the Emunot V'deot of Rassag which was popular even in his own day in Europe. His views certainly do not reflect those of his successors. Rabbi, especially those who don't have training outside of the realm of halacha, sometimes say wacky things. I am not aware of _any_ subsequent thinkers who relied in him.

Comment: @mevaqesh The point is that this shita is not that one can argue "I see an old man with a white beard, it was G_d", all machloket is complex. Precisely for this I want to know what was

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39580/discussion-between-mevaqesh-and-kouty).

Comment: While not the actual text, [this essay](https://shiurimofravlopiansky.com/12%20Writings/The%20Corporeality%20Which%20Never%20Was.pdf) by R' Aharon Lopiansky sheds significant doubt on the classic assumptions about R' Moshe Taku's beliefs.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi David Sedley wrote an article about Moshe Taku and his corporealist views, in contrast with Rambam and Saadiah Gaon. In the article, he translates sizeable segments of Ktav Tamim which expressly describe his opinions. The article is available here: http://www.hashkafacircle.com/journal/R3_DS_Taku.pdf

I understand you requested the original text. As it is, we do not have the complete Ktav Tamim today. For the purposes of understanding Moshe Taku's stance, Rabbi Sedley's translation does a quality job.

Comment: @kouty: I took the liberty of sending R' Sedley a link to this question.

Comment: @MichaBerger Waw. the topic is very strong for me. A great discovery wtih a great potential of understanding a lot of actual approach to Judaism.

Comment: This is absolutely not a subject for me. and I believe not for anyone else either.  But having said in the question "has a body", having glanced through the long article, I dont think that is what is meant, but "can" have a body. Meaning  doesnt usually have but can appear in a bodily form.  @kouty

Comment: @Micha Berger this debate remains for me a great source of thinking I guess that the approach of Jacques Lacan regarding the significant is the key of the sugia.