# Why btzelem elokim and not btzelem yud-kay-vav-kay?

Tags: theology, shemos-sacred-names

The torah states that humans are made btzelem elokim. We know that the shem elokim connotes middat ha-din. What ramification does this have on humans (if any)? Why were humans not made btzelem the shem Hashem that connotes mercy (yud-kay-vav-kay), especially if we have a mitzvah (v'halachta b'drachav) to be merciful just as God is merciful.

Comment: Can you source your first two sentances? also that the mitzva vehalachta bedrachav has anything to do with mercy?

Comment: Note also that shem Havaya doesn't show up at all in the first creation story.

Comment: @DoubleAA When is the first time Shem HaShem is used in the Torah?

Comment: @Yehoshua Breishit 2:4

Comment: Establishing a justice system is a law for b'nei Noach, but being merciful isn't.  I don't know if that's the reason; it's just an observation.

Comment: <a href="http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8874">See_answer_here.</a>

Comment: [See answer here.][1] I think that should do it.
  [1]: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8874

Comment: @Shalom Use this syntax to link: `[words in brackets next to](http://link.in.parenthesis)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly to allow a person room to grow. [Kabbalah](http://www.kabbalaonline.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380712/jewish/Ibur-Yenika-Mochin-ch1.htm) sees a progression from the permutations of the name Elokim to the name Havaya (yud-kay-vav-kay). Perhaps we can say then that man is created in the image of Elokim and is given a goal and directive improve and mature to become more Godly (in the yud-kay-vav-kay sense).