# Is there a book containing references to contemporary responsa according to the order of the Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, jewish-books, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, shulchan-aruch

Is there a book containing references to contemporary responsa (maybe think starting from around the time electricity became common until now) according to the order of the Shulchan Aruch? I tried to do some research and I found two books:

- Piskei Tshuvos (publisher unclear)
- Otzar HaShu"t (Mechon Maharshal, on Hebrewbooks)
- Otzar HaPoskim (publisher unclear)

However, neither of the first two books cover anything other than Orach Chayim. Also, Otzar HaShu"t, while it does cover many early and some modern authorities (such as Igros Mosheh, according to [the list at the end of the first volume](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21598&st=&pgnum=265)), it omits many others. I haven't had enough time to examine Piskei Tshuvos very carefully, but I have looked at some of it before and have not seen a modern authority whose name I know mentioned (but from such a small sample that could be expected).

[Otzar HaPoskim](http://www.eichlers.com/otzar-haposkim-11-vol-set-avcr-hpvsqim-abn-hezr-11-krkim.html) seems to be only on Even HaEzer. It seems that the first (of eleven) volumes is on Hebrewbooks [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/36140). He does seem to quote modern authorities (e.g. [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36140&st=&pgnum=133&hilite=) note 27 he mentions a "shlita"), and he also quotes earlier achronim from other places that wouldn't be easily found, but I also didn't have a lot of time to examine it. In any case, it doesn't cover the other three parts of the Shulchan Aruch.

Is there any other book that has references to contemporary rabbis' works like these? Preferably it would have their actual psak and not just a reference to look in their book. Also, it would be preferable if it has all four parts of the Shulchan Aruch, but books with fewer than that are also valuable.

Comment: Maybe something like http://torahmusings.com/2012/10/weekly-freebies-peninei-halakhah/, as recommended at Torah musings?

Comment: Eugh. Sorry, thought I'd be able to embed that link.

Comment: @ShimonbM http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21786/why-btzelem-elokim-and-not-btzelem-yud-kay-vav-kay#comment49477_21786

Comment: @ShimonbM It seems to be a good and clear book, but it's not in the order of the Shulchan Aruch

Comment: [Thanks](http://torahmusings.com/2012/10/weekly-freebies-peninei-halakhah/), @DoubleAA!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any one set that covers all four sections of Shulchan Aruch, but there is an excellent computer program called [Otzros Hashut - Otzar Haposkim](http://www.talsys.net/?d=article&cat=products&id=15) that has [4000](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw0YJe5WHHvWUjBNclR0S3ZIclk/edit?pli=1) scanned in responsa linked by Siman in Shulchan Aruch and topics if you are willing to invest in it.

Also, not in the order of Shulchan Aruch but a good place to look for contemporary Halacha is ["Hamafteach Hagadol" by Rabbi Feitel Levin](http://books.google.com.au/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C.html?id=GfolAQAAIAAJ); an index of contemporary responsa.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a set that covers all parts of the Shulchan Aruch. However, I just recently have been coming across the Dirshu Mishna Berurah which has a section that details piskei halacha from authorities since the time of the Chofetz Chaim. This can be of particular help in Hilchot Shabbat, but of course will only cover the section of Orach Chaim rather than all of Shulchan Aruch. Maybe a good start. Here is a review I read:
http://matzav.com/dirshu-edition-of-mishna-berurah-chelek-gimel-revolutionizes-the-learning-of-hilchos-shabbos